# How to delete all words except numbers and a given list?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to delete all the words in a string except the numbers and a given list ('dummy' is used as an example here). I have been able to make some progress and reached the following stage.

```
$s =~  s/[^\W\-\,0-9\s\.{dummy}]//g;
```

There are two problems with this — the words which are subset of dummy are not deleted and it leaves out characters like `%` etc.

Here are the sample outputs.

Input String: `I scored 75% in the final examination.`

Output String: `d 75%    m.`

But the output should be `75 .` instead.

EDIT:
It may not have been clear from the wording of my question but I also need to have the punctuation marks like the '.' at the end or any other place without disturbing the order in which they appear. Please note that I also need to remove special characters like the carriage return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For punctuation you can use the Unicode class 'Punct'.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'I scored 75% in the final examination.';
$s =~ s/\b(dummy|final)\b|[^\d\p{Punct}]/$1 if defined $1/eg;
print "$s\n";
```

However, it includes both `.` and `%`.
So as to keep particular punctuation marks you might want to define your own set.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'I scored 75% in the final examination.';
$s =~ s/\b(dummy|final)\b|[^\d.,;]/$1 if defined $1/eg;

print "$s\n";
```

Comment: This doesn't take car of the special words which also need to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

`$s =~ s/\D+//g;` for this example that should be fine. \D is = NON NUMERIC.

Or you need the last dot?

Comment: I also need punctuation as well. Sorry I forgot to add it in the question. I will edit it now.